# How to add commands of windows to local shell of XShell 4

Tags: windows, command-line, terminal, shell, shell-script

XShell is a very powerful tools to ssh remote computers such as Unix/Linux. And it has built some internal commands for you to run within your Windows.

```
Xshell:\> help
Internal Commands:
new:      Creates a new session.
open:     Opens a session or the session dialog box.
edit:     Opens the Session Property dialog box for a session.
list:     Lists information of all available sessions.
          'ls' and 'dir' do the same.
cd:       Changes the current working directory.
clear:    Clears the screen/address/command history.
help:     Displays this help. '?' does the same.
quit:     Quits Local Shell. 'exit' does the same.
ssh:      Connects to a host using the SSH protocol.
telnet:   Connects to a host using the TELNET protocol.
rlogin:   Connects to a host using the RLOGIN protocol.
sftp:     Connects to a host to transfer files securely.
ftp:      Connects to a host to transfer files.

External Commands:
ipconfig: Configures TCP/IP network interfaces.
ping:     Sends ICMP ECHO_REQUEST packets to network hosts.
tracert:  Prints the route packets take to network host.
netstat:  Displays current protocol statistics and current
          TCP/IP network connections.
nslookup: Resolves a hostname to IP address.

For more information, type 'help command' for each command.
ex) help telnet
```

But these commands are limited, so how to add commands of windows to local shell of XShell 4

Comment: Off topic, XShell is a commercial application for MS Windows

Answer (score 2):

### Unfortunately

NetSarang has not added this ability to xShell (as of version 4).

The only option for now, is to make a suggestion on their forum.
Like this post: http://www.netsarang.com/forum/xshell/1901/sol

### However

that does not mean we are without options until they decide to add this feature **`:)`**

You just have to be comfortable with using a Hex Editor. (Highly Recommend: [**`HxD`**](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/))

**Note** this will require that you replace one of the existing external commands.

1. Open the xShell install directory (usually: `C:\Program Files (x86)\NetSarang\xShell 4`)
2. Make a copy of `xShell.exe` and name it `xShell.bak.exe` (This will be a backup.)
3. Open `xShell.exe` in [**`HxD`**](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/)
4. Do a Search/Find (`Ctrl + F`) for one of the following commands:

   - ipconfig
   - ping
   - tracert
   - nslookup
5. Now replace that command with `cmd` (For my example, I replaced `ipconfig` with `cmd`)

   - This allows me to use the full cmd interface within xShell.
   - Disclaimer: Know that there will most likely be some issues. This is not supported behavior!
6. Before:
   [image]
7. After:
   [image]
8. Save the changes to `xShell.exe` and you are done.
9. Enjoy **`:D`**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
External Commands:
```

See that part of the help? It's allowing you to *run arbitrary Windows commands* locally. Such as `ipconfig`.

Try `cmd` or `shutdown` or `notepad`. If it's in your `PATH` environment variable, you should be able to run arbitrary Windows commands from this shell. Of course, I don't own a copy of XShell, so I can't actually test this theory, but you should *try it*.

XShell may not be flexible enough to execute arbitrary Batch script (if it doesn't support the same syntax), but you could run `cmd.exe` or a `.bat` file to get access to `cmd` scripting.